# new grails 3 intellij project "Content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle

A brand new, empty grails 3.2.8 project.  Intellij does its gradle thing and comes up with an error "Content is not allowed in prolog".  What is going on? What content, what prolog?  There is nothing under the Gradle tab, the grails-app structure is there in the project, but no Grails under the Tools tab.  What is going on?  Why can't Intellij build an empty project? How do I get around this?

Update - by running the cmd "grailsw --stacktrace compile" I see the following, does this provide a clue?  (Just the start of the stacktrace is shown).

```
Error initializing classpath: Content is not allowed in prolog. (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/Jay/.gradle/caches/modul
es-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.3.7.RELEASE/7beb5752c6d33f3d112
6fba306d0554c24b735d7/spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.pom; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber
: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.
java:257)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Doc
umentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomRea
der.parseToDom(PomReader.java:249)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomRea
der.access$100(PomReader.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomRea
der$2.transform(PomReader.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.parser.PomRea
der$2.transform(PomReader.java:134)
        at org.gradle.internal.resource.AbstractExternalResource.withContent(Abs
tractExternalResource.java:96)
```

Comment: Usually see this on malformed xml, do you have a corrupt xml file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.pom in the cache was corrupt - just a bunch of nuls in the file.  I deleted the file, causing it to be refreshed and at that point the prolog content error stopped appearing.

Comment: And to finish, I had to drop back to grails 3.2.5 to create a project that would build - 3.2.8 projects would not.  I don't know about later versions such as 3.2.10, haven't loaded them yet.